# jQuery map plugin does not load in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I've created the following jsFiddle which includes as resources Google Maps API and the [gMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/) jQuery plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/thompcha/Th8xS/2/

However, I am unable to make the map load. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it uses deprecated API and old version of jQuery, look at origin page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gmap plugin is horribly out of date.  Google Maps API version 2 requires an API key which is only valid on one particular domain.  (It won't work on jsfiddle.net without an API key registered specifically for the jsfiddle.net domain.)

The new Google Map API (v3) does not require an API key.  It's also [easier to use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) so you shouldn't need jQuery or a separate jQuery plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/222/